# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : serilog subloggers configuration related problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

As the title says, I'm struggling with Serilog's subloggers configuration (from `appsettings.json`).

I am trying to have two subloggers: the first one is going to log only information level logs that I sent from services, and the second one must log everything (likely to ASP.NET Core default logging) to a console.

Now I will post two `appsettings.json` snippets that I tried and explain what they are doing

With this one both subloggers are logging only logs sent from services (probably due global Microsoft error namespace overriding):

```json
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Error"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
                "connectionString": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=AuctionDb;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;Encrypt=False",
                "tableName": "ActivityLogs",
                "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
                "autoCreateSqlDatabase": false,
                "columnOptionsSection": {
                    "customColumns": [
                        {
                            "ColumnName": "UserId",
                            "DataType": "nvarchar"
                        },
                        {
                            "ColumnName": "ItemId",
                            "DataType": "int"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            },
            "MinimumLevel": "Verbose"
        }
    ]
}
```

This one causes console log everything as needed, but the database sublogger doesn't log anything:

```json
"Serilog": {
     "MinimumLevel": {
     "Default": "Information"
     },
     "WriteTo": [
      {
       "Name": "MSSqlServer",
       "Args": {
         "connectionString": "Server=localhost01\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=AuctionDb;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;Encrypt=False",
        "tableName": "ActivityLogs",
        "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
        "autoCreateSqlDatabase": false,
        "columnOptionsSection": {
          "customColumns": [
            {
              "ColumnName": "UserId",
              "DataType": "nvarchar"
            },
            {
              "ColumnName": "ItemId",
              "DataType": "int"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
        "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      },
      "MinimumLevel": "Verbose"
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand where the problem can be, but still can't fix that after many attempts

Comment: can you elaborate on this --> *"probably due global microsoft error namespace overriding"* Since you think this is the problem it might help to have more explanation.

Comment: @topsail this two json configurations differ only in "Override": { "Microsoft": "Error" } section(second one doesnt have at all)
as i think by overriding microsoft error i can exclude unnecessary logging and therefore i see only logs called from my code.
But i cant explain why removing this one causes database logging not working Hope i could explain it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's seems that i got it working properly

this is a working `appsettings.json` configuration:

```json
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information"
  },
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Expressions" ],
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
        "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Logger",
      "Args": {
        "configureLogger": {
          "WriteTo": [
            {
              "Name": "MSSqlServer",
              "Args": {
                "connectionString": "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=AuctionDb;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;Encrypt=False",
                "tableName": "ActivityLogs",
                "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
                "autoCreateSqlDatabase": false,
                "columnOptionsSection": {
                  "customColumns": [
                    {
                      "ColumnName": "UserId",
                      "DataType": "nvarchar"
                    },
                    {
                      "ColumnName": "ItemId",
                      "DataType": "int"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "Filter": [
            {
              "Name": "ByExcluding",
              "Args": {
                "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.')"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Solution was to filter out `Microsoft.` namespace errors with `Serilog.Expressions` package and ensuring that it will be used in `Using` section of Serilog configuration.

Comment: This does not seem to match your original problem (which was NO logging) since by adding an excluding filter you are doing less logging (which means the problem was TOO MUCH logging). However, glad it is working!

Comment: @topsail  Yeah, you a right, serilog tried to log events from Microsoft namespace which dont  have any property matching the custom columns I added to my database sink and due to the fact that this columns dont allow null values serilog was throwing an exception. I wasnt aware that there is self-logging feature in serilog, it really helped me to debug this issue. And it took me a while to find a way to override Microsoft namespace ONLY for the database sink.

Comment: I see. This makes me wonder if you could have got the original error (due to the column nullability) by looking at the Serilog [self-logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics).

Comment: if  you want I can try to reproduce this situation and send you exception serilog  was throwing after enabling self-logging